# Old path referenced when using Terminal after removing Enthought Canopy App

Tags: python, macos

I was using Enthought Canopy Application to learn basic Python.
After I was done I removed the App.

But now I can not use the Python at all even from the terminal.
I re-installed python and it did install into the default framework catalog.

Despite that, when I run the version check, it references the Canopy App catalogue:

```
Micheles-MacBook-Air:~ Michele1$ python --version
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Python
  Referenced from: /Users/Michele1/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Looks like Canopy brought Python and when you uninstalled Canopy, you also removed python. Have you tried installing a new Python, like from fink, mac ports, homebrew, or such?

Comment: Thabk You, works ok now with 2.7